# Data Validation Character Limit Exceeded with Substitute Function

Tags: excel, validation, substitution

I have a Data Validation that is dependent on another cell, hence the Indirect function, however, I need to replace all special characters with an underscore (_). I had no problems with this until I reached the max character limit of 256 in the Data Validation formula. Is there any way to consolidate the Substitute function so I don't need to repeat it for each special character i need to substitute with an underscore?

NOTE** I am unable to use macros or VBA as this is a template that is loaded into another application that only accepts .xlsx files.

Here is my current formula that is too long:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(N2,"/","_")," ","_"),"&","_"),"-","_"),"(","_"),"'","_"),"*","_"),")","_"),",","_"),CHAR(10),"_"),":","_"),";","_"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by not putting everything into the DV formula.

Instead, create a named formula, aka named range (with the Name Manager on the Formulas ribbon) using your substitutes without the Indirect and use a **relative** reference to the row. You need to take care to place the active cell into the correct row when defining the formula, because the row reference without the $ sign is relative to the current cursor position. If the first dropdown is in row 2 and you want the dependent dropdown in row 2, then place the active cell into row 2 and use this formula in a new range name called "DependentList":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$A2,"/","_")," ","_"),"&","_"),"-","_"),"(","_"),"'","_"),"*","_"),")","_"),",","_"),CHAR(10),"_"),":","_"),";","_")
```

This formula will dynamically re-calculate for each row and you can then use the result in the DV list definition, wrapping it in Indirect().

[image]

The setup in the above screenshot should be self-explanatory. Here you can see it at work

[image]